# How to avoid this `System.IO.IOException`

Tags: c#, text-files, console-application

```
public static void Main()
{    
    string username = "", password, chkusername;
    bool vald, chk;
    vald = false;
    string choice = "Y";

    while (choice == "Y")
    {                        
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("Users.txt", FileMode.Append, 
            FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Username : ");
        var Createnew = File.ReadAllLines("Users.txt");`
        chkusername = Console.ReadLine();
        foreach(string Dummies in Createnew)
        {
            string[] userline = Dummies.Split('#');

            if(userline[0].Equals(chkusername))
            {
                vald = true;
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("username already exists please choose another");
                Console.ReadKey();
                Console.Clear();
                break;
            }

            chk = vald;
            if (vald == true)
            {
                Main();
            }

            while(choice == "Y")
            {
                username = chkusername;
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a Password : ");
                password = Console.ReadLine();

                sw.WriteLine(username + "#" + password);
                sw.Flush();
                sw.Close();
                fs.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("Username Created");
                Console.WriteLine("Do you want to continue ? Y/N");
                choice = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }           
    }
}
```

I get an exception here:

```
 var Createnew = File.ReadAllLines("Users.txt");
```

> System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file
>   'C:\Users\admin1\source\repos\LumberJackProgram\LumberJackProgram\Users.txt'
>   because it is being used by another process.'

Comment: You put a stream close _inside a loop_. What do you expect to happen the second time the loop is iterated through? The stream it's handling will be closed. Consider putting your stream in a `using` block around the whole thing.

Comment: start by putting `var CreateNew = File.ReadAllLines("Users.txt");` above `FileStream fs = new FileStream . . .`, then see what the next error is...

Comment: By the way, to solve this... just read the whole file _before_ all this, so you have the original state at a moment the file is not in use yet. Also consider only opening, writing to and closing the file at the moment you actually have your information.

Comment: your code is extremely poorly formatted on SO, correct this, dont put the exception you are getting in the middle of the code.

Comment: @RufusL System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\admin1\source\repos\LumberJackProgram\LumberJackProgram\Users.txt' because it is being used by another process.' it doest change

Comment: Open the file for both reading and writing (one stream) outside the loop. Do not use multiple streams and do not open it inside the loop.

Comment: That recursive call back to `Main()` seems extremely dangerous too... if you want to restart the loop at that point, use `continue`, don't call the function again.

Comment: Also you need to rethink your approach, or design, or algorithm because what you want to accomplish is straight forward but to me it seems your code is telling you what to, while it should be the other way around. It seems you do not have a solution but you are working through trial and error and letting the debugger push you around. You have 2 loops and you are even using recursion--are you aware of that? In other words, exception is not the only problem you have.

Comment: In this case a `do while` is the loop to use and the `while` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First process the Users.txt file storing each name in an [HashSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) collection of strings

```
HashSet<string> names = new HashSet<string>();
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("Users.txt");
foreach(string line in lines)
{
    string name = line.Split('#')[0];
    if(!names.Contains(name))
       names.Add(name);
}
```

Now you can ask your user to enter the information needed and check against the HashSet if the name is already there or not

```
while (choice == "Y")
{
     Console.WriteLine("Enter Username : ");
     chkusername = Console.ReadLine();
     if(names.Contains(chkusername))
         Console.WriteLine("Name already entered");
     else
     {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a Password : ");
        password = Console.ReadLine();
        names.Add(chkusername);

        // Write the file in append mode and close/dispose it
        using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("Users.txt",true))
            sw.WriteLine(chkusername + "#" + password);

     }
     Console.WriteLine("Continue? Y/N");
     choice = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

In this way you don't mix the reading part with the writing part. Also you don't need to recall the Main method to reenter this code if the name exists in your file

Comment: Why would you keep opening the stream for writing within the loop? It is better if opened once outside and then closed after the loop.

Comment: Yes it would be better. But on the other side this will keep the file in use for a limited time.